# How to prove hexadecimal address for a java object store in the memory of heap

Tags: java

I want to know that this hexadecimal address is in the heap of memory?On the stack?How to prove?

```
public class Arr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("The memory address of the arr array is：" + arr);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C12g.jpg)
thank you all

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How exactly did you obtain the address for the java object?

Comment: The system identity hash code is a random number, not the address.

Comment: All objects are in the heap.

Comment: There is no way in natural java to obtain the range of the heap. Note the address of an object can change when the GC runs which can occur at any time making the actual address only indicative.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a memory address. It is a result of toString representation of you object. In fact you invoke String.valueOf(arr) and it equivalent to invoke arr.toString().

```
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Its not a memory pointer - its a hashCode generated from object. If you take a look inside bytecode you got this

```
invokevirtual java.lang.Object.hashCode() : int [68]
invokestatic java.lang.Integer.toHexString(int) : java.lang.String [67]
```

And all you need to getting this result is a take hashCode from object and convert it to hex

```
    System.out.println("Out:" + arr);
    System.out.println("Out:" + String.valueOf(arr));
    System.out.println("Out:" + arr.toString());    
    System.out.println("Out:" + Integer.toHexString(arr.hashCode()));
```